# Need a way to read passed Jenkins job parameters and check them before the job start building

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

How could I check passed job parameters before the job start building.

Based on the result of applied conditions for passed parameters, if result is True, I will start the build, if result is False, then skip the job without even start the build and then abort it or make it as Failure/Unstable.

Note, I know I can do that inside the job itself in Jenkinsfile, by check the passed parameters there. But I would like to do that in way so that I don't need to start build job directly.

I think what I'm looking for is such as Pre-Build procedure.

> If Pre-Build == True:
>   -> Start Build
>  Else
>   -> Skip the build at all

Is there a plugin or a workaround can help in that please ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Parameters are part of a job. A ”valid paramter" parameter can only be determined in the context of a job. The only thing that would know what is a valid is the logic inside the job. Therefore bthe job must be triggered to do the evaluation.

You could create a generic trigger job which took your parameters, did some universal validation and the triggered the actual job, passing validated parameters in.

But what would you achieve by that? There are many extended build parameters plugins (including choice parameter) which only let the user pick from available options.

Comment: Thanks @lan for your help. Actually I have a github webhook which triggers Jenkins job when Pull request is created. On Jenkins side, I have a parameter called payload which contains the Pull request info, 
The issue here is that Pull request contains all events (approved,closed,merged,etc). So I'm do filter on payload and check if it contain event approved for Pull request. So that I'm looking to have a way to do the check outside the job not during the execution.